# What to do if HTTP Content-Length differs from actual body size?

Tags: http, http-headers

If a HTTP server sends a reply with a Content-Length header and a message-body that is slightly larger than that length, what is the accepted way to handle this mismatch? Should I silently ignore the extra data? I don't see this specified in the HTTP/1.1 RFC, it just says that it should always match. Just seems like there could be some buggy servers out there that don't get this right.

Thanks.

Comment: How much is slightly? Can the difference be explained by some encoding?

Comment: @Oded Shouldn't it still match even if it uses different encoding?

Comment: @gigadot - UTF8 and UTF16 have different amount of bytes for some of the same characters.

Comment: Yes, but the content length should be the actual number of bytes in the stream so it still need to match

Comment: @Oded, e.g. if the encoding change then the content lenght must be changed too

Comment: @gigadot - I am just trying to look for explanations.

Comment: @Oded Right, so you mean the content length might be wrongly set using the number of characters instead of the number of bytes.

Comment: @gigadot - Just a possibility.

Comment: Server-side code may be wrong, it could be a silly mistake, or something more subtle like proxying the content-length from another wrong source, it could be many things like using char count instead of real byte count ...

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Response.Clear()
 Response.ClearHeaders()
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", CStr(oOutputStream.Length))
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; Filename=abc.pdf")
 Dim statement(CInt(oOutputStream.Length)) As Byte
 oOutputStream.Position = 0
 oOutputStream.Read(statement, 0, CType(oOutputStream.Length, Integer))
 Response.BinaryWrite(statement)

 Response.Flush()
 Response.End() -- do you see anything wrong in this code? server is sending more than of content length data in my case.

Comment: @MohanSharma As stated in other answers this could be due to compression. I do not even know what language your stuff is in, looks like VB ... post a new question on SO with appropriate tags.

Comment: Note: if you're getting this error in NextJS App Router, see solution here: https://janac.medium.com/nextjs-fails-with-und-err-req-content-length-mismatch-after-redirect-from-server-0acdc0bfb194

Answer (score 5):

I tested this with a `CSV` file in Chrome and Firefox.

Declaring too small `Conent-Length` resulted in both browsers silently discarding the extra bytes, leaving the end of the file truncated.

Not declaring any `Content-Length` seemed to cause no problems. The download was complete.

Declaring too large `Content-Length` resulted in two different behaviors:
Chrome saved a `.part` file containing the entire `CSV`. Chrome is expecting more "parts" to complete the file.

Firefox declared a download failure. I didn't see the "partial' file anywhere, but the browser's UI presents a "retry" button.

Answer (score 4):

The length is defined by the Content-Length header field (or Chunked Encoding, or closing the connection).

If the length doesn't "match" this means that the extra bytes belong to the next message. If these extra bytes do not represent an additional HTTP message, that's a communications error. Just close the connection and report an error.

(see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#message.body.length)

Comment: No this is not right. see the fact is there is compression on the server side and the content length can in fact be less than what is actually received in the body of the response.

Comment: cynistersix what counts is the declared content length (in absence of other information). Check the spec.

Comment: @JulianReschke citation required.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you're arguing with one of the actual authors of the HTTP specification.

Comment: I am absolutely fine doing that and would still like a citation. Being able to do that is part of what makes both this site and open standards pretty great. The fact a citation was indeed added for the benefit of future readers is a testament if that :)

Answer (score 0):

By HTTP status code definitions, returning a "400 Bad Request" and informing the client in response that the two lengths mismatch seems to be the most appropriate action.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

10.4.1 400 Bad Request

The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

Comment: I don't think that's correct, it's the server who sends the mismatched data, the client did not send a bad request to cause this.

Answer (score 0):

For any passerbys from NextJS receiving a similar error, try switching from fetch to axios.

For a full solution, see here: https://janac.medium.com/nextjs-fails-with-und-err-req-content-length-mismatch-after-redirect-from-server-0acdc0bfb194