# requests.head.headers['content-length'] different than len(requests.get)

Tags: python, file, https, size, python-requests

I'm trying to get a file size before actually downloading it.

My code currently looks like this:

```
r = requests.head(url)
print r.headers['content-length']
r = requests.get(url)
print len(r.content)
```

The output is

```
188
33901
```

The file size is actually `33901`, the `url` starts with `https` if that matters

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314051/what-to-do-if-http-content-length-differs-from-actual-body-size though there's no answer there either.

Comment: I can't share it cause it includes a private VirusTotal API key.